# Why is the Hadoop HDFS -rmr command super fast

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In one of my folders on the HDFS, i have about 37 gigabytes of data

> hadoop fs -dus my-folder-name

When i execute a

> hadoop fs -rmr my-folder-name

the command executes in a flash. However on non-distributed files systems, an rm -rf would take much longer for a similarly sized directory

Why is there so much of a difference? I have a 2 node cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is that when you issue hadoop fs -rmr, the Hadoop moved the files to .Trash folder under your home directory on HDFS. Under the hood I believe it's just a record change in the namenode to move the files location on HDFS. This is the reason why it's very fast.

Comment: So when does Hadoop permanently delete the contents of the Trash folder?

Comment: @Mo. look at theses arguments: `-skipTrash`, `-expunge`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in an OS, a delete command deletes the associated meta data and not the actual data and so the reason why it is fast. The same is the case with the HDFS also, the block might be still in the DN's, but all the references to them are removed. Note that the delete command frees up the space though.